# proof $a$ ,$b$ and $c$ can be sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry

$a$,$b$ and $c$ are three number such that:

$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2>2(a^4+b^4+c^4)$

proof that $a$,$b$ and $c$ can be sides of a triangle.

**My Attempt:** I have tried to make this unequal simpler but nothing happened maybe we don't have to make it simpler.I don't know but should we prove the triangle sides unequal for all of them?finally I can't know what should I do with this unequal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: 
$$
(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)>0
$$
Because $c<a+b$, $b<c+a$ and $a<b+c$ since $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the LHS gives
$$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 = a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + 2(ab)^2 + 2(bc)^2 + 2(ac)^2$$

This simplifies the original equation to:
$$2(ab)^2 + 2(bc)^2 + 2(ac)^2 > a^4 + b^4 + c^4$$
$$4(ab)^2 > c^4 - a^4 - b^4 -2(bc)^2 - 2(ac)^2 + 2(ab)^2$$
$$4(ab)^2 > (c^2 - a^2 - b^2)^2$$
$$2ab > c^2 - a^2 - b^2$$
$$c^2 < a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$$
As we know by the cosine rule
$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2abCosC$$
we also know $$2ab > -2abCosC$$ $$1 > -CosC$$ and  $C$ cannot be an angle greater than $180^o$ as it is in a triangle

This means that $$a^2 + b^2 - 2abCosC <a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$$
which then proves $$c^2 < a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$$
making your statement true.